# Lost apachectl bin file

Tags: macos, apache

How can I recover the apachectl on my OSX?

I deleted it, somehow, and now the command apachectl doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Do you... have any backups? use Time Machine? have the 10.8 install media?

Comment: `/usr/sbin` isn't in your PATH usually. What does `ls -l /usr/sbin/apachectl` return?

Comment: @jscott I have a Macbook Pro, there is no install media, and no, I don't use Time Machine, at least until it happened.

Comment: @patrix returns `ls: /usr/sbin/apachectl: No such file or directory`

Comment: @patrix In lieu of [building apache from Apple's source](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/apache/apache-780/), it may be quicker to find another 10.8 user and get a copy from them.

Comment: Will installing the OSX combo update restore any files installed by Apple? Currently 10.8.2 is [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1581)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On 10.8 apachectl is a ~50 SLOC shell script. I uploaded the one from my installation [here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=jND2h3B1). For example `apachectl start` just runs (sudo) `launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist`, so you don't necessarily even need apachectl.

Answer (score 0):

If you [build Apache httpd](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/install.html) from the source code, you can get the `apachectl` binary from `<apache_src_dir>/support/apachectl`.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Can you please elaborate the answer to explain how one can rebuild apache from source?